# Redshift : could not complete because of conflict with concurrent transaction

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm having this error : could not complete because of conflict with concurrent transaction.

And I don't find the other query conflicting with this one.

I've tried :

- Using the AWS charts/metrics within the online console.
- Looking in STL_TR_CONFLICT
- STL_QUERY selecting queries running at the same time of mine failing.

None of these options help me to understand the issue. I've found some queries running at the same time but they were not using the same tables.

Relaunching the query few minutes later worked just fine.

Comment: i have the same issue, did u find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

I just found I got this issue when the following transactions were running at the same time:

1. `drop` / `create my_schema.my_table as ...`
2. `grant select on all tables in schema my_schema` <-- this one failed